# OData & .NET Web API

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, odata

I'm new to OData and I have a question about using it in my .NET Web API.  In my web API if I have a controller with the following Get method:

```
[EnableQuery()]
public IQueryable<Product> Get()
{
     var productRepository = new ProductRepository();

     return productRepository.Retrieve().AsQueryable();
}
```

Is it necessary for me to retrieve all products before the OData query options are applied or is there a way for me to only retrieve products using the OData query options?

I wouldn't want to have to retrieve all products which could be over 100,000 and then have the OData query options applied to only return like 10 records based off of my criteria.

Thanks for any help with this question.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are returning the collection as an IQueryable, you haven't actually got all of the data, the filters will be applied to it for you. [Here is a nice explanation of how IQueryable works with entity framework.](http://www.developerhandbook.com/2013/11/24/in-the-spotlight-demystifying-iqueryable-entity-framework-6/) OData Web API is just converting the OData URLs into LINQ statements that are executed at a database level.

Answer (score 0):

> A malicious or naive client may be able to construct a query that
>   takes a very long time to execute. In the worst case this can disrupt
>   access to your service.
>
> The [Queryable] attribute is an action filter that parses, validates,
>   and applies the query. The filter converts the query options into a
>   LINQ expression. When the OData controller returns an IQueryable type,
>   the IQueryable LINQ provider converts the LINQ expression into a
>   query. Therefore, performance depends on the LINQ provider that is
>   used, and also on the particular characteristics of your dataset or
>   database schema.
>
> If you know that all clients are trusted (for example, in an
>   enterprise environment), or if your dataset is small, query
>   performance might not be an issue. Otherwise, [you should consider the
>   following recommendations](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-security-guidance).

I your case you would be interested in:

```
// Enable server-driven paging.
[Queryable(PageSize=10)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example is almost the *minimal* necessary to enable the OData query options to be applied. Because you are returning the collection as an [`IQueryable<>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable?view=net-6.0), the evaluation of the data has not yet occurred and the `EnableQueryAttribute` will be able to apply any *default* or passed in options to your query for you immediately before retrieving the data and serializing it into the response.

> **NOTE:** If you do pre-load the data, even if you still return an `IQueryable` response, the `EnableQueryAttribute` will only be able to apply the options to the data that you have loaded. The `EnableQueryAttribute` can only affect the data or query that is returned from your controller logic.